# Maintaining VS Code settings is rather cumbersome - What's required to create a Tools > Options dialog box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maintaining the VS Code settings appears rather cumbersome to me:

- You never know which particular setting you have actually changed
- You don't find anything in the huge list of settings.

I wonder if I could create a Windows style Tools > Options dialog box for VS Code. What would be required to actually have such dialog box added to (my personal) VS Code? (E.g. where can I get the contents of the default settings, incl. comments? How can I add something to the VS Code menu?)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point might be to use the [vscode.workspace.getConfiguration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#1648) function without any parameters.

This function returns the merge of default, global (user), and workspace configurations.